# PL/pgSQL: Trigger Function returning incorrect data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function with parameters "select_date" and "sponsor" that is supposed to return some data a table based on the values passed as parameters:

```
SET search_path to Olympic;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_finance.sponsor_name%type)
RETURNS SETOF sponsor_data LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
      sp_data sponsor_data ;
BEGIN
      SELECT 
                 tb_sponsor.email,
                 tb_finance.sponsor_name,
                 tb_athlete.name,
                 tb_discipline.name,
                 tb_register.round_number,  
                 tb_register.register_measure, 
                 tb_register.register_position,
                 DATE(tb_register.register_ts)
                
       INTO sp_data
       FROM olympic.tb_sponsor
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
      ORDER BY tb_sponsor.email ;

      RETURN NEXT sp_data ;
END ;  
$$;
```

The function works partially, but it RETURNS incorrect values. When I use parameters '2021-06-02 00:00:00', 'Adidas' where 'Adidas' is the sponsor, it RETURNS sponsor_name as VISA:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_get_info_by_sponsor('2021-06-02 00:00:00', 'Adidas')

sponsor email, sponsor_name, athlete_name, discipline_name, round_number, register_measure, register_position, register_ts,
  NULL  "VISA"  "JACOBY Lydia"  "Swimming"  1   NULL    3   "2021-06-07"
```

Can anybody see what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
CREATE TYPE sponsor_data AS (
email email_type,
sponsor_name CHARACTER VARYING(100),
athletes_name CHARACTER VARYING(50),
discilpine_name CHARACTER VARYING(50),
round_number  INT ,
mark CHARACTER(12),
register_position INT,
register_ts  DATE
);
```

Comment: Well, you don't use the parameters in a WHERE clause to limit the result. And you only return the first row of the query as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name should the SETOF statement RETURN the set of rows?

Comment: No, the "return" statement returns something from the function. You are returning a single row with your return statement.

Comment: Well you run `return next` **once**, so you only return a single row.

Comment: `RETURN SETOF` is part of the function's definition. It does not return anything. `return next` returns one row each time you run it. Your code only runs `return next` **once**, so your function will never return more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

For a PL/pgSQL function returning `setof` you have to use the `RETURN QUERY` clause, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_finance.sponsor_name%type)
RETURNS SETOF sponsor_data LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
      SELECT row(
                 tb_sponsor.email,
                 tb_finance.sponsor_name,
                 tb_athlete.name,
                 tb_discipline.name,
                 tb_register.round_number,  
                 tb_register.register_measure, 
                 tb_register.register_position,
                 DATE(tb_register.register_ts)
                ) :: sponsor_data 
       FROM olympic.tb_sponsor
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
      ORDER BY tb_sponsor.email ;
END ;  
$$;
```

or you can simply write a SQL user-defined function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_get_info_by_sponsor
       (register_date tb_register.register_ts%type, sponsor_name tb_finance.sponsor_name%type)
RETURNS SETOF sponsor_data LANGUAGE sql AS $$
      SELECT row(
                 tb_sponsor.email,
                 tb_finance.sponsor_name,
                 tb_athlete.name,
                 tb_discipline.name,
                 tb_register.round_number,  
                 tb_register.register_measure, 
                 tb_register.register_position,
                 DATE(tb_register.register_ts)
                ) :: sponsor_data 
       FROM olympic.tb_sponsor
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_finance
           ON (tb_finance.sponsor_name = tb_sponsor.name)
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_athlete
           ON tb_athlete.athlete_id = tb_finance.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_register
           ON tb_register.athlete_id = tb_athlete.athlete_id
      INNER JOIN olympic.tb_discipline
           ON tb_discipline.discipline_id = tb_register.discipline_id
      ORDER BY tb_sponsor.email ;
$$;
```

Comment: thank you (: TheRETURN QUERY did not solve my issue. I receive the: ERROR: cannot open SELECT query as cursor.

Comment: Your problem is not inside the function `fn_get_info_by_sponsor`, it is in the way you call this function inside a `CURSOR` ! Please show the function code where you call the function `fn_get_info_by_sponsor`.

Comment: This is how I call the function: SELECT * FROM fn_get_info_by_sponsor('2021-06-02 00:00:00', 'Adidas')

Comment: I have updated my answer but I'm not sure it will solve your error. Can you please create your tables definition and insert a data sample in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) so that we can analyse your problem ?